# Powering Raspberry Pi 4 With OnePlus Charger 5V 4A

Tags: pi-4

I´m planning on buying Raspberry Pi 4 and i don't want to waste money on a charger if the one that I have for my phone technically works.

I can save a few bucks for buying the case alone. I don't use it because I don't want to lower the phone battery life so I use an original Samsung 2A charger.

I heard that not all chargers works well with RPI 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any device that supplies 4 amps at 5 volts will work to power the Pi4B.

Comment: But if it uses a 'smart' USB-C cable it may well not work.

Comment: See https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/07/raspberry-pi-4-uses-incorrect-usb-c-design-wont-work-with-some-chargers/ for information regarding non-compliant USB-C power in the Pi 4.

Comment: Pi 4 Revision 1.2 fixed the USB-C non-spec power problem. Released around Feb 2020. See ["How to Check if Your Raspberry Pi 4 Model B is Rev1.2?" on tutorial.cytron.io](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2020/02/22/how-to-check-if-your-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-is-rev1-2/)